# vscode markdown sparql syntax highlighting in fenced code blocks

Tags: markdown, sparql, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code

I'm wondering what to do to get syntax highlighting for a [SPARQL query](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) that I write in a  [Markdown](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) fenced code block.

So far, I noticed that in edit mode I can get a result if I use `s` as a language, but:

- sadly, the markdown preview seems to ignore it: no effect is obtained
- I do not know if the rules for parsing `s` have actual correspondence with SPARQL

[image: screenshot of markdown and preview in vscode]

Also, I found something in [vscode-fenced-code-block-grammar-injection-example](https://github.com/mjbvz/vscode-fenced-code-block-grammar-injection-example), but I'm not sure I understand how it works and I would like to know if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: I don't think there's a simpler solution, that's how it's done.